# Executing SSIS package from PowerShell with different Environments References

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, powershell, ssis

I am trying to execute an SSIS package from Powershell where th,e package has several configured environment references.

```cs
$null = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices")
$null = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc")

$ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + $LocalSQLServer
$SSISConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SSISConnection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$SSISConnection.Credential = $LocalSQLCredential

$SSIS = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.IntegrationServices
$SSIS.Connection = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SqlStoreConnection $SSISConnection

$SSISCatalog = $SSIS.Catalogs["SSISDB"]
$SSISFolder = $SSISCatalog.Folders[$TargetFolderName]
$SSISProject = $SSISFolder.Projects[$ProjectName]
$SSISPackage = $SSISProject.Packages[$PackageName]

$SSISEnvironmentReference = $SSISProject.References | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $EnvironmentName} #Get the environment reference 

$SSISPackage.Execute("False", $SSISEnvironmentReference)
```

When I execute this script, I get an exception:

```
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Execute" with "2" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo' threw an exception."
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace.STraceSource' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlContext' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace.STraceSource..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace.STraceSource.get_TraceSources()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace.TraceContext..ctor(String eventSourceName, String eventContext, String eventSubcontext)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace.TraceContext.GetTraceContext(String eventSourceName, String eventContext, String eventSubcontext)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace.TraceContext.GetTraceContext(String eventSourceName, String eventContext)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo.ScriptCreateExecution(Boolean use32RuntimeOn64, EnvironmentReference reference)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo.Execute(Boolean use32RuntimeOn64, EnvironmentReference reference, Collection`1 setValueParameters, Collection`1 propetyOverrideParameters)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String , Object )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

Any clues on why the 2nd parameter is throwing an error? If I pass $null (as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-powershell?view=sql-server-ver16 and 90% of the examples I have seen) still get the same error.

Comment: If you do something like `$SSISEnvironmentReference | ConvertTo-Json -depth 1 | Write-Host` does the environment variable look like it's filled out?

Comment: Yes... Everything checks.